# How do I determine the number of the members in an enum?

Tags: c++, c++11

*Using C++11; MingW; Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:*

Given:

```
    enum TMyEnum
    {
        Enum_1, Enum_3, Enum_3
    };
```

What function will tell me how many members are in TMyEnum, in this case 3?

Comment: What is your final goal? and note you're not using c++11 enum's there: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick is to provide a count item at the end such as:

```
enum TMyEnum
{
    Enum_1, Enum_2, Enum_3, 
    Enum_4, Another_Enum, 
    Enum_count
};
```

Then `TMyEnum::Enum_count` should provide the cardinality of your set of enumerations. Just make sure you add new enumerations before `Enum_count`. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5c65b31eca0a7b3):

```
#include <iostream>

enum TMyEnum
{
    Enum_1, Enum_2, Enum_3, 
    Enum_4, Another_Enum, 
    Enum_count
};

int main() {
    std::cout << TMyEnum::Enum_count << std::endl;   
}
```

### Output

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use it with default values, you can have like following :

```
enum TMyEnum
    {
        Enum_1, Enum_3, Enum_3, No_of_Enums
                                //^^=3
    };
```